# How do you extend a modern collection view cell's default content configuration?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Apple's [Displaying Cell Info](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/displaying-cell-info) tutorial shows using a default cell content configuration to set two lines of text

```
    func cellRegistrationHandler(cell: UICollectionViewListCell, indexPath: IndexPath, id: String) {
        let reminder = Reminder.sampleData[indexPath.item]
        var contentConfiguration = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        contentConfiguration.text = reminder.title
        contentConfiguration.secondaryText = reminder.dueDate.dayAndTimeText
        contentConfiguration.secondaryTextProperties.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
    }
```

How would I get started extending this to include a third line of text? I would like to keep the built-in `text`, `secondaryText`, and accessory control (the tutorial has a done button on each cell), while also adding custom UI elements. I'm assuming this is possible since Apple uses the term "compositional collection views," but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Is it possible, or would I instead need to register a custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass?

Comment: also - quick tip I found while first looking at this - be careful creating your cell registration handler with an instance method (like your `cellRegistrationHandler` listed above). If you do invoke it with a strong reference to self, you could cause a memory leak (even that tutorial from Apple you mentioned did this...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use custom `UIContentView` and `UIContentConfiguration` objects to accomplish what you're talking about.

that being said, here's a simplified example of a content config/view/collection-list -

```
// MARK: UIContentConfiguration

struct MyCellContentConfiguration: UIContentConfiguration {
    var text: String?
    
    func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView {
        MyCellContent(configuration: self)
    }
    
    func updated(
        for state: UIConfigurationState
    ) -> MyCellContentConfiguration {
        self
    }
}

// MARK: UIContentView

class MyCellContent: UIView, UIContentView {
    var configuration: UIContentConfiguration {
        get { cellConfiguration }
        set { configureCell() }
    }
    private var cellConfiguration: MyCellContentConfiguration
    private weak var label: UILabel!
    
    init(configuration: MyCellContentConfiguration) {
        self.cellConfiguration = configuration
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        addLabel()
        configureCell()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func addLabel() {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        self.label = label
    }
    
    private func configureCell() {
        label.text = cellConfiguration.text
    }
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewController

class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    typealias DataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, String>
    typealias Snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, String>
    
    private var dataSource: DataSource!
    
    init() {
        let configuration =
        UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .grouped)
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout
            .list(using: configuration)
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // register cells
        let cellRegistration =
        UICollectionView.CellRegistration<
            UICollectionViewListCell, String
        > { cell, indexPath, text in
            var contentConfiguration = MyCellContentConfiguration()
            contentConfiguration.text = text
            cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
        }
        // configure datasource
        dataSource = DataSource(collectionView: collectionView) {
            collectionView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(
                using: cellRegistration,
                for: indexPath,
                item: itemIdentifier) }
        // configure snapshot
        var snapshot = Snapshot()
        let items = ["Ayo", "what da dog doin?"]
        let sections = [items]
        let sectionKeys = [Int](0..<sections.count)
        snapshot.appendSections(sectionKeys)
        sectionKeys.forEach {
            snapshot.appendItems(
                sections[$0],
                toSection: $0) }
        // inject snapshot & datasource
        dataSource.apply(snapshot)
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSource
    }
}
```